# how can i emulate a request like a web browser does?

Tags: php, browser, emulation

When I am looking at 
https://www.tutti.ch/de/vi/zaurich/haushalt/geraate-utensilien/tassen-und-unterteller-arv-ikea-blaue-streifen/27002681
with a browser, I see a complete other site than when I use:

```
file_get_contents(...) // or

$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,...);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);`
```

How can I get the html code like seen with the browser?

Comment: It has JS code that renders parts or the compete page. You need headless browsers or testing enviroments like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/).

Comment: it is not possible to do it with just PHP?

Comment: There are a few headless browsers for PHP you can try but these are third party software and need to be installed using `composer`: [headless-chromium-php](https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php) and [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte).

Answer (score 1):

The html on this website is rendered in the client side by the browser using javascript. If you are trying to parse some content from the website, try using a headless browser. A headless browser is a browser that works without the graphical interface, but behaves like a normal browser. Both Chrome and Firefox have headless versions.

Here is a useful lib to query headless browsers with php: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver
You can also interact with the javascript send commands like a real user would do.

You may install the browser and the driver in a different machine (or even your own pc) if you don't have the necessary permissions to do it in your hosting account.